# Drawing images from an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dictionary

I'm currently working on drawing up a tilemap using a set of images loaded inn to an array.

I've defined a tile as an object like this:

```
function tile(gfx){
this.tile = gfx;

this.drawSelf = function(x,y)
this.tile.x = x;
this.tile.y = y;
}
```

Then I filled up an array with several tile objects which through the debugger displays correctly.

Now when I start drawing up the images using this code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < mapArray.length; x++){
xN = 183 + (50*x);
mapArray[x].drawSelf(xN, 134);
gameStage.addChild(mapArray[x].tile);
mapArray[x].tile.visible = true;
}
```

The problem is that all the "objects" in the array recive the same x and y coords. So what i suspect is that every single object in the array referes to each other.

What I'm trying to do is create a 20x10 map of tiles. And I need to be able to refer to each tile as a single object.

Shout out if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create all the tiles like this :

```
var gfx = new ...
for (...) {
    mapArray[x].tile = new tile(gfx);
}
```

Then all of them share the same `gfx` object.

You should change your initialization like this :

```
for (...) {
    var gfx = new ...
    mapArray[x].tile = new tile(gfx);
}
```